# Delete rows in one minute intervals with Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a very large table in a PostgreSQL DB with 3 columns: SENSOR_ID, VALUE, TIMESTAMP. I  have values every 5 seconds for different SENSOR_IDs. I would like to delete rows in such a way that I keep **1 VALUE per SENSOR_ID per minute**. That way I could reduce the size of the table significantly.

Comment: Can you give examples of the timestamps?

Comment: If you have multiple inserts per SENSOR_ID per minute, which one would you like to keep?  The most recent?

Comment: @youngthing I think OP wants the ones that happen at 00s. Sergi, don't you want to average those values to reduce noise, outlier influence etc. instead of just discarding those?

Comment: Timestamp looks like this: "2014-05-13 15:38:13.025+02". I do NOT want to average values, I would like to keep the first value for every minute which maybe in different time depending on the sensors (not all the sensors send values at same time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delete from t
using (
    select
        sensor_id,
        date_trunc('minute', "timestamp") as "minute",
        min((extract(epoch from "timestamp") / 12)::integer * 12) as "epoch"
    from t
    group by sensor_id, 2
) s
where
    sensor_id = s.sensor_id
    and
    date_trunc('minute', "timestamp") = s.minute
    and
    extract(epoch from "timestamp") / 12)::integer * 12 != s.epoch
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient strategy here would be to create a function to trim the excess for the current minute, and to execute the function every time that data is inserted.

A trim function would remove excess and may be expensive if you don't take care.  Running it only when data is inserted and only for the minute and SENSOR_ID that the data contains limits the scope for speed.

Create the trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggername 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON tablename 
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE functionname
```

Create the function using your preferred language, e.g. plpgsql.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is something that I could implement in the future but the answer that I was looking for has been provided by Clodoaldo Neto.